# Python failure when running Nikola in Windows 8?

Tags: python, windows, nikola

I've installed Nikola using pip and am trying to run it, but Python continues to crash in Windows 8. I've updated to the latest version of Python and tried a number of installs and Nikola with no luck.

From reading a bit it sounds like this has something to do with the difference in executable scripts between UNIX and Windows. Any advice?

Comment: When you say Python crashes, what exact error message do you receive?

Comment: Nothing appears in command line, but a small window pops up with "python.exe has stopped working".